# Inno Setup: Close installer wizard if file exists in the program's folder

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to create an installer that is a Demo installer that if it detects the file `close.txt` in the programs folder then it closes the wizard or aborts install.

I am running a scheduled task that automatically uninstalls the app after two days. On initial install the `close.txt` file gets installed in the programs folder then after auto uninstall the `close.txt` file is left in the programs folder. I would like for when you re run the installer it checks for this file and if it is found to close the wizard or abort install. I am a newbie at this I think it can be accomplished in the code section but I am not sure.

Any help or code snippets would be appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test for the file existence in [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup) and return `False`, if it exists.

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={autopf}\My Program
```

```pascal
[Code]
function WasMyProgramEverInstalled: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FileExists('{#SetupSetting("DefaultDirName")}\close.txt');
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if WasMyProgramEverInstalled then
  begin
    MsgBox('Some message', mbError, MB_OK); { Optionally }
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

*Note that if the installer allows customizing an installation path, you won't know it, when re-running the installation after uninstallation. So this won't work.*

Comment: Thanks Martin I had it close and working but I think your solution is very clean I was doing function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
    MsgBox(ExpandConstant('Install'), mbInformation, MB_OK);
    if HasRequirements() then begin
        MsgBox('Demo Expired.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
        result := false;
    end else
        result := true;
end;